# Stop post truncating Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll

I am using a jekyll template to create a blog, currently all posts are truncated with a read more link.
I wish to remove this and have posts of any length fully displayed.

Here is my index.html

```
---
layout: default
---

{% for post in paginator.posts %}
<article class="main-article">
  <div class="wrap-content">
    <header class="header-article">
      <h2 class="title-article"><a href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
      <div class="post-date"><span>{{post.date | date: '%Y, %b %d'}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
    </header>
    {% if post.img %}
       <img class="post-image" src={{ "/assets/img/" | prepend: site.baseurl | append: post.img }} alt="{{post.title}}">
    {% endif %}
    <p>{{post.description}} <a class="more" href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}">(Read more...)</a></p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: '//', '/' }}" class="previous"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Previous</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="previous"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Previous</span>
  {% endif %}
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path | prepend: site.baseurl | replace: '//', '/' }}" class="next">Next <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="next ">Next <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `post.description` is used in the font matter. In your case the read more links to the post.url which is the associated post. Read more about real excerpts here: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts